# Is Monocross platform is suitable for developing simple mathlogic realated games?

Tags: c#, mono, monocross

I am new to the **monocross** platform , i want to develop a simple MathLogic Game for kids which supports **Iphone** and **Android** , so i want to know weather Monocross was right flatform to develop or is there any disadvantages ?.

Please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can't comment on monocross currently, but I suspect experience and limitations are similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224376/mvvmcross-experiences-hindsight-limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MonoCross help and advice, try their Google Group - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/monocross-developers

They are much more active on that group than they are here.

However, I would suggest you explain more in your question there - I haven't got a clue what "a simple MathLogic Game for kids" is - some rough screenshots might help.

---

For more general games, also consider MonoGame - http://monogame.codeplex.com/